# Importing project library from github giving unexpected behaviour

Tags: android, github

I am using first time git hub library in my project and new to android.I am trying to make project in which i need to use graph for this I am using ease graph project from git hub but it is giving me an error

Error:(9, 0) Could not find property 'file' on SigningConfig_Decorated{name=release, storeFile=null, storePassword=null, keyAlias=null, keyPassword=null, storeType=null}.

this is the file coding available

```
    apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 21
    buildToolsVersion "21.1.2"

    signingConfigs {
        release {
            storeFile file(STORE_FILE)
            storePassword STORE_PASSWORD
            keyAlias KEY_ALIAS
            keyPassword KEY_PASSWORD
        }
    }

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "org.eazegraph.app"
        minSdkVersion 9
        targetSdkVersion 21
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }

    lintOptions {
        abortOnError false
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'

            signingConfig signingConfigs.release

            // this is used to alter output directory and file name. If you don't need it
            // you can safely comment it out.
            applicationVariants.all { variant ->
                variant.outputs.each { output ->
                    def file = output.outputFile

                    String parent = file.parent
                    if (project.hasProperty('OUTPUT_DIR') && new File((String) OUTPUT_DIR).exists())
                        parent = OUTPUT_DIR

                    output.outputFile = new File(
                            parent,
                            (String) file.name.replace(
                                    ".apk",

                                    // alter this string to change output file name
                                    "-" + defaultConfig.versionName + "-build" + defaultConfig.versionCode + ".apk"
                            )
                    )
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile project(':EazeGraphLibrary')
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:21.0.3'
}
```

any help please..

Answer (score 2):

It seems you have not defined the variables `STORE_FILE, STORE_PASSWORD, KEY_ALIAS, KEY_PASSWORD` in your script. You can do it as follows :

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
def STORE_FILE= "File location goes here"
def STORE_PASSWORD= "Store password"
def KEY_ALIAS= "Alias to use"
def KEY_PASSWORD= "password to the alias"

android {
   ....
}
```